# Delete 2d subarray from 3d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy I have a 3d array and I would ike to remove some of the 2d subarrays. Think about it like this:

```
r = range(27)
arr = np.reshape(r, (3,3,3))

del = [[0,1,2],[0,0,2]]
flatSeam = np.ravel_multi_index(del, arr.shape)
arr = np.delete(arr, flatSeam)
```

So at the end I would like to have an array of the shape `(3,2,3)` without the elements `00, 10, 22` from the original array. My problem is that I acn not use `ravel_multi_index` for this, because my indices are 2d and the array shape is 3d, so the wrong indices are calculated (the code above also does not execute because the indices array and the shape have to be the same size).

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: So, the first row of `del` would always be `range(arr.shape[1])`, like you have `[0,1,2],` here ?

Comment: The first row of `del` should be `range(arr.shape[0])`. So first row are the row indices and the second row are the column indices.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
# arr: Input array, rm_idx : 2-row list/array of indices to be removed
m,n,p = arr.shape
mask = np.asarray(rm_idx[1])[:,None] != np.arange(n)
out = arr[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.where(mask)[1].reshape(m,-1)]
```

Alternatively, with [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) -

```
out = arr.reshape(-1,p)[mask.ravel()].reshape(m,-1,p)
```

A bit less memory-intensive approach as we try to avoid creating `2D` `mask` -

```
vmask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(m*n),rm_idx[1] + n*np.arange(m))
out = arr.reshape(-1,p)[vmask].reshape(m,-1,p)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! From which namespaces comes `rm_idx`? Oh sorry this is my `del` array right?

Comment: @Cilenco `rm_idx` would be your `del`. I used a different variable name as there's `del` operator in Python, so that might cause conflict.

Comment: Ah okay good point! But with this I get following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` in the mask line

Comment: @Cilenco I was assuming it to be an array. Edited to accept both arrays and list.

Comment: Ah yes okay. Works great now :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: The order of the `rm_idx` array is for this solution not important, isn't it?

Comment: @Cilenco Do you mean the first row of `rm_idx`? I assumed it to be `range(arr.shape[0])` as per the comments. The order of second row of `rm_idx` doesn't matter.

Comment: @Cilenco Any issue still remaining with the posted solution on your use case?

Comment: No no it's all right! I had the range in reversed order. When you asked about the `range(...)` I haven't thought about the order, but more about that each row is present in the array. I have accepted the answer now. Thanks again for your help!